# Excel: Dynamic hierarchy formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Task**: Creating a dynamic hierarchy value for each input row of an excel Table (examples in table column *Check*).

**Requirements**:

- No VBA,
- Dynamic table formula which accommodates changes in level quantity and content,
- Numbering based on table column *Order*.

**Problem**: Current version of the formula in table column *Hierarchy* (see below) seems to produce #VALUE! -errors during the iteration resulting in incorrect hierarchy values.

**Question**: **(A)** What is wrong with the current formula? OR **(B)** How could the hierarchy value be determined to accomplish the task given the requirements?

**Current formula**:

```
=LET(Levels;SUM(IFERROR(SEARCH("Level ?";Current_costs[#Headers]);0));
     Range;OFFSET([@[Level 1]];;;;Levels);
     Depth_bool;--(NOT(TRIM(Range)=""));
     Depth;SUM(Depth_bool);
     Comparison;EXPAND(IFERROR(SEQUENCE(Depth;;;0);0);Levels;;0);
     Depth_join;TEXTJOIN("";FALSE;Depth_bool);
     Comparison_join;TEXTJOIN("";FALSE;Comparison);
     Bool_similarity;--(Depth_join=Comparison_join);
     Bool_empty;--(NOT(Depth=0));

IF(AND(Bool_similarity;Bool_empty);LET(Full_range;TRIM(CHOOSECOLS(Current_costs[#Data];SEQUENCE(Levels)));
                                        Full_concat_range;BYROW(Full_range;LAMBDA(A;TEXTJOIN("";TRUE;A)));
                                        Hierarchy;TEXTJOIN(".";TRUE;BYROW(SEQUENCE([@Depth]);LAMBDA(A;INDEX([Order];MATCH(CONCAT(INDEX(Range;SEQUENCE(A)));Full_concat_range;0)))));
                                        Hierarchy); ""))
```

[image]

**Notes**:

- The second LET() -formula, nested in the first one, is the one that
  determines the hierarchy value currently. It's nested to reduce
  computation if the level content inputs are erroneous.
- Duplicates or empty input values need not be checked as the full
  version of the table already includes error checking.

**Table**: *Current_costs*

| Level 1 | Level 2 | Level 3 | Level 4 | Depth | Order | Hierarchy | Check |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A |  |  |  | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| A | B |  |  | 2 | 1 | 1.1 | 1.1 |
| A | B | C |  | 3 | 1 | 1.1.1 | 1.1.1 |
| A | B | C | E | 4 | 1 | 1.1.1.1 | 1.1.1.1 |
| A | B | C | F | 4 | 2 | 1.1.1.1 | 1.1.1.2 |
| A | B | C | G | 4 | 3 | 1.1.1.1 | 1.1.1.3 |
| A | B | D |  | 3 | 2 | 1.1.1 | 1.1.2 |
| A | B | D | H | 4 | 1 | 1.1.1.1 | 1.1.2.1 |
| A | B | D | I | 4 | 2 | 1.1.1.1 | 1.1.2.2 |
| J |  |  |  | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| J | K |  |  | 2 | 1 | 2.2 | 2.1 |
| J | K | L |  | 3 | 1 | 2.2.2 | 2.1.1 |
| J | K | L | M | 4 | 1 | 2.2.2.2 | 2.1.1.1 |

Comment: Are the values per each level unique? A on Level1 would always be 1, and if there would b a B it would be 2 etc.?

Comment: Are you seeking for an answer on what's wrong with the formula, or are you looking to create the `Check` values based on the input in Level 1 - 4?
Also, is the formula to be part of the table (new column) or in a regular cell aside of the table?

This for instance spills the checks:
`=LET(z,LAMBDA(x,SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(BYROW(DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(x)),LAMBDA(i,y,HSTACK(i,IF(INDEX(x,,y)="","",XMATCH(INDEX(x,,y),UNIQUE(TOCOL(INDEX(x,,y),1)))))))&" ",,1),CONCAT))," ",".")),z(A2:D10))`

Comment: @Ike I have a formula in the full table that checks for duplicates. They don't have to be checked in the hierarchy itself.

Comment: @P.b Either or. Solving either (A) OR (B) is fine, I just need a functioning solution. The hierarchy formula is a part of the table.

Comment: I provided a solution. Let me know that works also if there's different `order` for for instance `Level 1`

Answer (score 1):

Edit to match the changed question:

```
=LET(prevhier,INDEX(Current_costs[[#All],[Hierarchy]],ROW([@[Level 1]])-1),
     levels,  SUM(N(LEFT(Current_costs[#Headers])="L")),
     t,       TEXTSPLIT(prevhier&REPT(".0",levels-1-(LEN(prevhier)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(prevhier,".","")))),"."),
SUBSTITUTE( TEXTJOIN(".",,IF(TAKE(Current_costs[@],,levels)="",
                             0,
                             IF(TAKE(Current_costs[@],,levels)=INDEX(TAKE(Current_costs[#All],,levels),ROW([@[Level 1]])-1,SEQUENCE(,levels)),
                                IFERROR(t+0,0),
                                IFERROR(t+1,1)))),
            ".0",""))
```

This uses no LAMBDA, just compares to the values (and result) above.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this out. In the second screenshot the hierarchy value of <Level 1> = "B" should correspond to 2, i.e. The hierarchy value on row 8 should be 2.1.1.1 and not a duplicate of row 5.

Comment: Also, in an ideal case the formula should minimize the amount of loops and look-ups as the table could be thousands of rows long, which is why my original attempt was with only one loop.

Comment: I see what you mean at `Level 1` `B` should correspond to 2, see updated answer.
Not sure what you mean by different loops versus 1 loop.

Comment: Never mind, I mixed up TOCOL() and BYCOL() and thought you had nested loops which would reduce the efficiency, but you only have MAP() for the iteration.

Comment: True. If you think this answered your question, please mark the question as answered by clicking the ✔️ next to the answer.

Comment: Can you modify the answer to rely on the Order column? I tested the formula on the full data and it fails to differentiate Level 4 if Levels 1-2 are identical but Level 3 is different. Relying on the precalculated Order column would solve the issue. Ill add it to the requirements.

Comment: Can you update the sample with examples of that?

Comment: Maybe `=IF([@[Level 1]]=OFFSET([@[Level 1]],-1,,),IF(COUNTA(Current_costs[@[Level 1]:[Level 4]])=COUNTA(OFFSET(Current_costs[@[Level 1]:[Level 4]],-1,,)),TEXTBEFORE(OFFSET([@Order],-1,1,),".",-1,,,OFFSET([@Order],-1,1,))&"."&[@Order],OFFSET([@Order],-1,1,)&"."&[@Order]),IFERROR(TEXTBEFORE(OFFSET([@Order],-1,1,),".",1)+1,1))` it's currently unreproducable with your data

Comment: I added more table rows.